# Split block design with crossed main effects and a random effect in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, split-plot

I am having trouble specifying a model in lme4.

Your help with be greatly appreciated!!
And please let me know if I can improve how I ask this question.

I am looking at the impact of light, temperature and fungicide on disease levels for a set of plants (plant=observational unit).

I think the design is a split-block with crossed main effects (i.e each level of one factor occurs in each level of the other).

The temperature (high or low) is the first effect applied (n = 100 per treatment). Within each temperature treatment, light and fungicide are split (n = 50 for each level of temperature/fungicide , and n = 25 for each unique combination of temperature, light and fungicide).

Please take a look below for an illustration of this data in table format. There is also a blocking factor which refers to the location of the plants.

I currently have the following model but can't work out how to include the split plot/crossed structure.

happy_plant_mod <- lmer(disease ~ tempt * light *  fungicide + (1 | block), data=mydata)

**Could you please advise me on this?**

E.g if the data set was a total n = 8, it would look like this.
Temp 1 = low   Nutrient = High fungicide = angry_stuff
Temp 1 = low   Nutrient = High fungicide = smelly_stuff
Temp 1 = low   Nutrient = low fungicide = angry_stuff
Temp 1 = low   Nutrient = low fungicide = smelly_stuff
Temp 1 = high  Nutrient = High fungicide = angry_stuff
Temp 1 = high  Nutrient = High fungicide = smelly_stuff
Temp 1 = high  Nutrient = low fungicide = angry_stuff
Temp 1 = high  Nutrient = low fungicide = smelly_stuff